# Mono on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, arm, mono

I've seen [a lot of talk about running Mono/.NET code on the Raspberry Pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9547047/monodevelop-armv6-raspberry-pi). Has there been any succceses in actually running any Mono code on the Raspberri Pi?

On their site, they list several Linux distributions that work on the device and some of these distributions include Mono. However, none detail whether Mono works on it.

Is there a working implementation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mono works absolutely fine on a Pi - we already have a tag and a [few dozen questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mono) on the topic.

Getting started should be as straightforward as punching in:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mono-complete
```